# Packaging LAME.exe with a C# project

Tags: c#, mp3, lame

Please forgive my noob-ness on this, but how do I package LAME.exe w/ a C# setup project?  Currently, I have LAME being called like:

```
//use stringbuilder to create arguments    
var psinfo = new ProcessStartInfo( @"lame.exe")
    {
         Arguments = sb.ToString(),
         WorkingDirectory = Application.StartupPath,
         WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden 
    };
var p = Process.Start( psinfo );
p.WaitForExit();
```

This works in debug and release modes on the development machine, but when I create a setup project for this, it never creates the MP3.  LAME and the compiled code reside in the same directory when installed.  Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> WindowStyle =
>   ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden

Comment this out so you can actually read the error message that lame produces.  Using a separate EXE is brittle this way, you cannot detect nor diagnose it failing to do its job.  You might see something from Process.ExitCode, non-zero values are supposed to indicate failure.

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't help.  The LAME process didn't stay on the screen long enough to be useful.

Comment: Run it with cmd.exe /k lame.exe *options* so the console window stays open.

Comment: Thanks, Hans.  Turns out it was a directory issue.

Comment: I should have specified more detail: the problem was in the call to LAME.  It contained a directory with a name like "this place".  The problem wasn't with the deployment.  Thanks, again, Hans for helping me troubleshoot this.